# google public dns and support for edns

Tags: dns

When i query the authoritative name server with dig (compiled with eDNS patch):

```
dig @ns1.google.com www.youtube.com +client=59.155.255.200

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.youtube.com.    86400   IN  CNAME   youtube-ui.l.google.com.
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 900    IN  CNAME   youtube-ui-china.l.google.com.
```

I get the IP address of youtube in China

but if i query google public dns for youtube.com using the same client subnet as above: 
    dig @8.8.8.8 www.youtube.com +client=59.155.255.200/32

I get a different list of IPs (basically the list is the same one i get from my local machine connected to a european ISP)

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
; CLIENT-SUBNET: 59.155.255.200/32/0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.youtube.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.youtube.com.    21599   IN  CNAME   youtube-ui.l.google.com.
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 299    IN  A   193.51.224.148
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 299    IN  A   193.51.224.154
```

My question is:
How does eDNS support work in this case? Isn't google public DNS supposed to forward my query with the client subnet i specified?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend upon "what" IP address the recursive name server (8.8.8.8 in this case) forwards to the auth nameserver.

In general, a recursor would choose to submit the **source IP address from the UDP packet** that a client sends as EDNS extension to the authoritative nameserver.